# Symfony2: Securing a route with 2 methods at same time

Tags: php, symfony

I have an admin area, that i am protecting with ROLE, in `security.yml`:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/addrating, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I want an extra pasword for all of us admin, that i would communicate over phone...so i thought to use http passwords....can i change my `security.yml` in a way that is enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want HTTP basic auth as an additional layer, you can just add this in your web server configuration without touching your Symfony security configuration.

For example in Apache, you could add this to /admin in the applicable vhost or a .htaccess file in web/admin.